# How can I set a session variable from a js inside haml in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby, session, haml

I have table row shading (for groups of row) via js.
I want to make it so that the shading is remembered through a session variable.

The haml partial I am using has:

```
Group Shading: 
  %a{:href => '#', :id => 'row_colors_on'}
    On
  %a{:href => '#', :id => 'row_colors_off'}
    Off
```

the js has:

```
$(function(){
$("a#row_colors_on").click(function(){
$(".row_color_group_1").addClass("color_group_1");
$(".row_color_group_2").addClass("color_group_2");
$(".row_color_group_3").addClass("color_group_3");
<%- session.group_shading = 'true' %>
event.preventDefault();
});
});
$(function(){
$("a#row_colors_off").click(function(){
$(".row_color_group_1").removeClass("color_group_1");
$(".row_color_group_2").removeClass("color_group_2");
$(".row_color_group_3").removeClass("color_group_3");
<%- session.group_shading = 'false' %>
});
});
```

the main page then uses:

```
- row_bg_color_group = 'row_color_group_1'
- for link in @links
  - construct_hyperlink(link.url_address, link.alt_text)
  - if link.group.group_name != (current_group ||= '') 
    - display_group = current_group = link.group.group_name
    - row_bg_color_group = rotate_rows_color_group
  - else
    - display_group = ''
   %tr{:class => "#{row_bg_color_group}"}
```

The code to change the background color of rows does do it but it is not remembered after a page refresh through the session variable ?

with the helper:

```
def rotate_rows_color_group
  if session[:group_shading] == 'true'
    cycle('row_color_group_1', 'row_color_group_2', 'row_color_group_3')
  else
   'row_color_group_1'
  end 
end
```

but I always get the 'else' condition, i.e. `session[:group_shading]` is not being either set or recognized

The css is

```
.color_group_1 { background-color: #133333; }
.color_group_2 { background-color: #122222; }
.color_group_3 { background-color: #111111; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use erb statements within javascript, it is parsed before it is send to a client. Instead use javascript `sessionStorage`:

```
$(function(){
$("a#row_colors_on").click(function(){
$(".row_color_group_1").addClass("color_group_1");
$(".row_color_group_2").addClass("color_group_2");
$(".row_color_group_3").addClass("color_group_3");
sessionStore.setItem('group_shading', true);
event.preventDefault();
});
});
$(function(){
$("a#row_colors_off").click(function(){
$(".row_color_group_1").removeClass("color_group_1");
$(".row_color_group_2").removeClass("color_group_2");
$(".row_color_group_3").removeClass("color_group_3");
sessionStorage.setItem('group_shading', false);
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('group_shading'))
    $("a#row_colors_on").click();
});
```

### Important note:

Note however that js session is sth else than your rails session. Rails session can be stored in various places and javascript has no access to it. This means you can't access those values on the server side. There are two solutions:

1) Use sessionStorage and execute some javascript depending on stored value after the page has loaded (as above).

2) Instead of using sessionStorage, send an ajax request to server to populate rails session (recommended).

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - This is a long story to tell. you need to create a new action in your controller to handle the request and then send a request. Youc an find examples of jquery AJAX at the botom of http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: k thanks.  I am trying the above method but page refresh still removes shading currently.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for those changes?

Comment: I commented out the conditional and found it isn't doing the 'click' anyway.

Comment: added the 'herlper' code... which is still using the rails session variable I guess... to the html pane.

Comment: where does the `sessionStore` function come from?

Comment: @vemv - `sessionStore` is an element of HTML5 and is supposed to be supported by majority of the modern browsers. Have a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @BroiSatse then you meant `sessionStorage`. that was confusing as there is Rails class called SessionStore!

Comment: @vemw - Gosh, thank you for noticing. Of course I meant `sessionStorage`. Fixing now.

Answer (score 1):

You can share state between Javascript (client-side) and Rails (server-side) with cookies. You can set a cookie in the view via Javascript (check out the js-cookie library), and read the cookies in a Rails controller.

Using the js-cookie library, you could set a cookie: (`Cookie.set('awesome', 'sauce')`) and then read it in the Rails controller: (`puts cookies['awesome']`).