# is it possible to set boolean value to a session variable based on some conditions, from javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session

I'm trying to set a boolean value to session from javascript in rails. my code is as follows

```
  function function_name(e){
  if (e.innerHTML == '+') {
      <% session[:open] = true %>
  }
  else {
      <% session[:open] = false %>
  }}
```

but i'm getting 'false' value to session[:open] always. conditions are satisfying when I put alert and checked. if this way is not possible, how can I set session value from javascript ?

looking for a solution other than ajax request to controller.

Comment: Probably this one would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846030/how-can-i-set-a-session-variable-from-a-js-inside-haml-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies if you don't want to make ajax requests. For first time visitors you may want to reload the page if the cookie isn't set.
This topic is nicely covered in this article (the backend is php but it really doesn't matter in this case): https://css-tricks.com/server-side-mustard-cut/